# Server side validation without closing JQuery (bootstrap) Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to create a login form in HTML that will do some server side validation of the fields.

In other words:

1. User clicks Log In button inside the dialog
2. Code sends data to
   server to validate.
3. Login dialog does not go away (but ideally shows
   some progress indicator)
4. If valid, goes to a new page. Otherwise
   dialog stays up and displays an error message

If using AJAX please also include server code, ideally in Python. But prefer not to use AJAX.

(I've read some some similar questions but I'm not clear if the are the same as what I want.)

Comment: You have to use AJAX if you don't want the dialog to go away.

Comment: SO is not here to write code for you. You should work on this yourself, and when you run into a problem post what you tried and ask specific questions.

Comment: Fair enough... but what overall strategy do you recommend? If AJAX is the only way then I will go down that path. I'd like the code to look similar to the question if possible (e.g. if (serverSideValidate() closeDialog())...)

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jquery-validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin. It has a [`remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) method that allows you to specify a URL that the field value will be sent to. The plugin takes care of all the complexities of dealing with the asynchrony of using AJAX. The method documentation has links to examples showing how to use it.